# minimum of values in pandas calculation

Tags: python, pandas, csv, min

I want to convert a piece of python code I wrote earlier to pandas so it is directly done in dataframe instead of messing with csv files.

I want to calculate the health of a device based on multiple values (attributes).
Lets say I have the following df:

```
   A   B  C
0  7 NaN  8
1  3   3  5
2  8   1  7
3  NaN 0  3
4  8   2  7
```

And I want to calculate the health as follows:

> note that the `def attributeHealth` is still in the old form and not
>   converted to pandas since that is the part where I get stuck and this
>   is the code that was working with the csv library

```
df['Health'] = attributeHealth(df['A'], 10, 0.4) * attributeHealth(df['B'], 5, 0.5) * attributeHealth(df['C'],2 ,0.8) * 100

def attributeHealth(name, weight, limit):
            if row[name] != 'NULL':
                attrHealth = 1 - min(int(row[name])*weight/100, limit)
            else:
                attrHealth = 1
            return attrHealth
```

I have tried reducing it to a single attribute first but it seems that I cannot use min() in this way:

```
inputDF['health'] = 1 - min(inputDF['A']* 2/100, 0.7)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your desired output in this example DataFrame?

Comment: I would be the original DF with an extra column 'health'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.minimum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.minimum.html) and then for replace missing values `reindex`:

```
inputDF['health'] = ((1 - np.minimum(inputDF['A'].dropna() * 2/100, 0.7))
                            .reindex(inputDF.index, fill_value=1))
```

Similar solution:

```
inputDF['health'] = 1 - np.minimum(inputDF['A'].dropna() * 2/100, 0.7)
inputDF['health'] = inputDF['health'].fillna(1)                      

print (inputDF)
     A    B  C  health
0  7.0  NaN  8    0.86
1  3.0  3.0  5    0.94
2  8.0  1.0  7    0.84
3  NaN  0.0  3    1.00
4  8.0  2.0  7    0.84
```

All together:

```
def attributeHealth(col, weight, limit):
    #return Series (column)
    return ((1 - np.minimum(col.dropna() * weight/100, limit))
                               .reindex(col.index, fill_value=1))

a = attributeHealth(inputDF['A'], 10, 0.4) 
b = attributeHealth(inputDF['B'], 5, 0.5) 
c = attributeHealth(inputDF['C'], 2, 0.8) 

inputDF['Health'] = (a * b * c) * 100
print (inputDF)

     A    B  C  Health
0  7.0  NaN  8   50.40
1  3.0  3.0  5   53.55
2  8.0  1.0  7   49.02
3  NaN  0.0  3   94.00
4  8.0  2.0  7   46.44
```

Comment: Thank you for the very complete answer, it was fun to see it evolve!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply) for this:

```
inputDF['health'] = inputDF.apply(lambda row: 1 - min(row['A']* 2/100, 0.7),
                                  axis=1)
```

`apply` executes the given callable (lambda, in this case) for each row and returns the resulting Series.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not familiar with the apply function but it seems very powerful and I will definitely look into it!